# Find whether a column is null or not in Dataset

Tags: datatable, null, dataset

How to find whether **a column in Data Table is Null (or) Not**. If my **Dataset(DS)** contains 1 Data_Table, and 2 columns. I want to check whether the **Column 2 is Null (or) Not**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you have one 2-column table in the dataset, then do...

```
isColumnEmpty = false;
DataColumn column = dataSet.Tables[0][1]; // get column 2 from table 1
foreach(DataRow row in column)
{
    if (row[0] == null) // check the only column of this row
        then isColumnEmpty = true;
    break;
}
```